# How to add "second placeholder" on Input text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to add a second text (required) in input text, diferent style/position of placeholder. But when user clicks, it should disappear, like placeholder. It's possible?

```
<style>
  .inputDataText{
    padding:13px; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:9px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#d9d9d9; 
    width:100%;
  }
  
</style>
<input id="demoTextBox" type="text" value="" class="inputDataText" placeholder="NAME">
```

Put an example image here:

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OXEx.png)

Comment: If you specified a fixed width for the input item, the you can add spaces into your existing placeholder text to push some text to the right.  These spaces are preserved when the text is being rendered

Comment: take a look at: https://codepen.io/Takumari85/pen/RaYwpJ the "Input with Label effects" at the bottom of the page. Its possible, yes, but you may need to work it out yourself.

Comment: Also, it is common to use `*` next to an input item and a note above or below all of them saying that these items are required.

Comment: Why not simply use "Name (required)" as a placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```css
.inputDataText{
    padding:13px; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:9px; 
    border-style:solid; 
    border-color:#d9d9d9; 
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .inputwrapper{
   position: relative;
  }
 .inputwrapper::after {
    content: attr(data-required);
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 15px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputwrapper" data-required="(required)">
<input id="demoTextBox" type="text" value="" class="inputDataText" placeholder="NAME">
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to answer this question as well, but @Lalji was faster :). However, here's a link to my implementation which is very similar: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/XWdGJNK

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the `:empty` pseudo selector

```css
.inputDataText:empty::after {
  // show something
}

.inputDataText::after {
  // hide something
}

You will have to play with the exact CSS, but that's the gist
```